# how to make slideshow smooth - jQuery GSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I have created a image slider, using the plugin [Extra slideshow](http://slider.extralagence.com/documentation/), this plugin is using Greensock and jQuery, but the problem is the sliding of the image is not smooth, if you notice, image is jerking while sliding.

Whats the expert suggestion here? how to avoid this jerk and make the slider super smooth, slideshow is going to be in full height/width screen .

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/zhxn4k3q/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // simple
    $(".extra-slider").extraSlider({
        draggable : false,
        keyboard  : true,
        auto: 7,
        speed: 5,
        pagination: $(".slider-wrapper .pagination")
    });
});
```

Comment: your jsfiddle link doesn't work, update it

Comment: It seems to be the `speed: 5,` try change it to 1

Comment: just updated the url..

Comment: @SanjeevK Reduce Images size and try it...

Comment: @SanjeevK as suggested by chirag reduce the size.. Size is more than 1 mb

Comment: your images are absolutely enormous, 1 of them over  10Mb in size, you're probably consuming far too much memory in the browser

Comment: okay, so optimizing size will reduce the jerk as suggested by @chiragsolanki